# use modifier $addToSet, $push or $pull with feathersjs and NeDB

Tags: feathersjs, nedb

How can I use the modifiers `$addToSet`, `$pull` or `$push` with a **NeDB** adapter for **feathersjs**? Following did not work and I cannot find anything in the documentation.

```
service('projects').update("<id>", { $addToSet: { assignedIds: "<newId>" } });
service('projects').patch("<id>", { $addToSet: { assignedIds: "<newId>" } });
service('projects').update("<id>", { query: { $addToSet: { assignedIds: "<newId>" } } });
```

I also tried to put the operator in the params like this (as stated in the document)

```
service('projects').update("<id>", { }, { 
    query: { $addToSet: { assignedIds: "<newId>" } } 
});
```

But the only thing I got back is **`unknown logical operator $addToSet`**

Comment: See https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/651

Comment: Ok, it was a bug indeed and got patched. I though I understood something wrong :) Thanks for the commit. If you want to post it as awnser I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, this was a bug in `featherjs` that got patched